Driver selection for second GPU
I want to change the used driver for the second GPU, since nvidia-smi can't recognize the second GPU.
But I can't change it anyway, since manually installed driver is selected. I have tried:
sudo apt remove nvidia-*
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

But these command only changed the driver for first GPU.
How can I change the driver option for second GPU?

Some logs for detailed condition
dmesg | grep -i nvidia
[    2.147839] nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    2.148164] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[    2.208048] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    2.221770] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 235
[    2.224437] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=io+mem
[    2.267950] nvidia 0000:21:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[    2.268433] nvidia 0000:21:00.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=none
[    3.772061] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  545.29.06  Thu Nov 16 01:59:08 UTC 2023
[    3.785219] nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  545.29.06  Thu Nov 16 01:47:29 UTC 2023
[    3.787569] [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Loading driver
[    5.348547] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20160202 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0
[    5.349356] [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00002100] Loading driver
[    5.781402] [drm:nv_drm_load [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00002100] Failed to allocate NvKmsKapiDevice
[    5.782243] [drm:nv_drm_probe_devices [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00002100] Failed to register device
[    6.986149] nvidia-uvm: Loaded the UVM driver, major device number 509.
[   10.640634] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:01:00.1/sound/card0/input19
[   10.640791] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:01:00.1/sound/card0/input20
[   10.640859] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:01:00.1/sound/card0/input21
[   10.640983] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:01:00.1/sound/card0/input22
[   10.641048] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:20/0000:20:03.1/0000:21:00.1/sound/card2/input12
[   10.641056] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:01:00.1/sound/card0/input23
[   10.641115] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:20/0000:20:03.1/0000:21:00.1/sound/card2/input13
[   10.641152] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=11 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:01:00.1/sound/card0/input24
[   10.641188] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:20/0000:20:03.1/0000:21:00.1/sound/card2/input14
[   10.641334] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=12 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:01:00.1/sound/card0/input25
[   10.641525] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:20/0000:20:03.1/0000:21:00.1/sound/card2/input15
[   10.641856] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:20/0000:20:03.1/0000:21:00.1/sound/card2/input16
[   10.642497] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=11 as /devices/pci0000:20/0000:20:03.1/0000:21:00.1/sound/card2/input17
[   10.643035] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=12 as /devices/pci0000:20/0000:20:03.1/0000:21:00.1/sound/card2/input18

lspci | grep -i nvidia
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 2203 (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1aef (rev a1)
21:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA102 [GeForce RTX 3090] (rev a1)
21:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1aef (rev a1)

sudo ubuntu-drivers devices

== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00002203sv00001462sd00005091bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
driver   : nvidia-driver-535 - third-party non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-520 - third-party non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-515-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-515 - third-party non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-470 - third-party non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-525-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-530 - third-party non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-470-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-510 - third-party non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-525 - third-party non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-545 - third-party non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

== /sys/devices/pci0000:20/0000:20:03.1/0000:21:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00002204sv000019DAsd00001613bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
manual_install: True
driver   : nvidia-driver-455 - third-party non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-460 - third-party non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-465 - third-party non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-495 - third-party non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.6

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What version of Ubuntu are you running? Please run lsb_release -a and Edit your question to include this information.

I'm sorry for the late reply. I'm back from holiday.
lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic

Oh, I just checked nvidia-smi now and it seems that the second GPU suddenly starts working:)

Ubuntu 18.04 has been End of Standard Support since June 2023 and is off topic here. Please upgrade to a supported version of Ubuntu.
